# Branch concept in svn vs git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-branch

I come from a `git` background so apologies for any gross svn-misconceptions causing this question.

In git, when switching between `branches`, the working copy is always say "adjusted" to reflect the staged files.

So e.g. when working in `branchA`, which incorporates a folder named `branchA-folder`, and the `master` branch does not have this folder yet, running `git checkout master` (ok, after having stashed or committed your changes) will make the folder `branchA-folder` "dissapear" from your filesystem (working directory), right?

Unless I am wrong, this allows `git` to maintain one local copy of your working dir which always reflects the (staged) status of your branch.

What is the case when it comes to `svn`?

1. Will the above switch (`svn switch <branchA-url>`) make the `branchA-folder` "dissapear"?
2. Does svn maintain *one actual copy* of the working dir per branch/tag?

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the relevant difference to take into account is that Subversion allows to check out as many working copies as you want and have them exist simultaneously because a working copy is just a directory with an attached repository URL. So when you switch to a branch Subversion assumes you want to keep your local changes and will just merge incoming changes into them (if any). It's also forced to assume that because there's currently no shelving feature: there's nowhere to save your changes for later.

*Disclaimer: I don't have any git background*

Comment: that was some really helpful info for an svn agnostic like me, thx!

Comment: So based in the overall discussion, could we say that in `svn` it is a good practice to keep a separate local folder for each branch / tag? Switching seems to be less seamless and more error-prone than in `git`.

Answer (score 0):

To understand how svn deals with things you need to realize, that SVN does not *really* support tags and braches. Branch/tag is just a copy of trunk directory placed in some other subdirectory. To make it manageable somehow, svn implements "cheap" copies (but only on server side).

> Will the above switch (svn switch branchA-url) make the branchA-folder "dissapear"?

Yes. It will be removed from working copy (if it is versioned by SVN). You can even do `svn switch ^/branchA-url/branchA-folder` - there is no difference between directory and branch from SVN point of view.

> Does svn maintain one actual copy of the working dir per branch/tag?

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly - SVN does not duplicate directory content in central server if `svn copy` was properly used to create a directory (or branch, or tag). No, if you did `cp` and `svn add` by hand. This is worse than git (every object in git "database" is stored exactly once).

Comment: Yes I was not very clear: I am not asking if it maintains multiple copies on the server, but rather whether the counterpart of `git checkout <branchname>` would (need to?) create a new _distinct_ local copy somewhere else (which is NOT the case with `git`). It just adjusts the working dir. Bottom line I guess is there is no 1-1 mapping for `svn` to `git checkout` (whether passing the `-b` flag for new branch creation or not.

Comment: It just adjusts working dir to represent what is stored under given path on server.